# How to add a woocommerce product to the custom Product_type using php code?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

A WooCommerce product is getting created easily but the product is getting added to the **product_type:simple**. I want to add the product to the **"custom product_type:test"**

```
static function createTicket($postId, $productDetails) {
$id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_title' => $productDetails['title'],
    'post_content' => $productDetails['description'],
    'post_status' => get_post_status($postId),
        'max_value' => 1,
));
update_post_meta($id, '_price', $productDetails['price']);
update_post_meta($id, '_regular_price', $productDetails['price']);
update_post_meta($id, '_wpws_testID', $postId);
update_post_meta($id, '_sold_individually', "yes");
wp_set_object_terms( $id, 'test', 'product_type' );
return $id;
}
```

I have added

> wp_set_object_terms( $id, 'test', 'product_type' );

But nothing works

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used [product_type_selector](http://hookr.io/filters/product_type_selector/) hook

```
// add a product type
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_custom_product_type' );
function add_custom_product_type( $types ){
    $types[ 'test_custom_product_type' ] = __( 'test Product' );
    return $types;
}
```

> Edit

Please check below links it help you more on this

- http://jeroensormani.com/adding-a-custom-woocommerce-product-type/
- https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-product-type-custom-settings-woocommerce/

> Edit

Above code for older version of WooCommerce

Used this code for save product with custom product type. it working with WooCommerce 3.*
Check this for more information https://gist.github.com/stirtingale/753ac6ddb076bd551c3261007c9c63a5

```
function register_simple_rental_product_type() {
    class WC_Product_Simple_Rental extends WC_Product {

        public function __construct( $product ) {
            $this->product_type = 'simple_rental';
            parent::__construct( $product );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_simple_rental_product_type' );
function add_simple_rental_product( $types ){
    // Key should be exactly the same as in the class
    $types[ 'simple_rental' ] = __( 'Simple Rental' );
    return $types;
}
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_simple_rental_product' );
```

Comment: I am already done with those steps. The custom product type is displayed under product_type dropdown. Now I want to assign a new product to the custom product type in backend

Comment: How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have added these too. Let me be more clear: I am trying to create a woocommerce product through my custom plugin. However product is getting added but to "Simple Product" and not "Test Product" I hope this makes some sense